# Oracle scheduler changes materialized view call into CTAS

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, scheduler, job-scheduling

I have a stored procedure that has this structure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE refresh_mv(p_mv_name VARCHAR2) AS
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '
      CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW ' || dbms_assert.simple_sql_name(p_mv_name) || '
      PARALLEL
      NOLOGGING
      NEVER REFRESH
      AS
      SELECT * FROM <biq_query>';
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
      'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW outside_view AS SELECT * FROM '||p_mv_name;
   -- DROP old mv?
END;
```

When this is executed from within SQL developer, OEM correctly displays a materialized view statement in the activity.  However, when this same procedure is run from the oracle scheduler inside of a chain, a create table as select statement is generated.  Is there some performance hit I am taking because of this and further why does the chain decide to use CTAS over MV?

Comment: Do you see a CTAS when you trace the CREATE MATERIALIZE VIEW session? It might be a dependent DDL that is always run with the CREATE statement but is only exposed somehow when run from the scheduler.

Comment: @VincentMalgrat good question, let me go turn trace on

Comment: Is there any DDL trigger that is used for Logging which fires on `CREATE`?

Comment: @Annjawn wouldnt the use of nologging preclude that?

Comment: I guess not. That would be the MV property but a DDL trigger is independent of that and would fire on any/specific DDL statement issued. But that's a long shot, because there is no reason for a DDL trigger to do a CTAS unless there is any custom stuff done by the DBA. A DDL trigger would be on a schema level though.

Comment: There is another possibility that could fire a CTAS which is the `ON PREBUILT TABLE` clause while creating the MV, but I don't see that being used.

Comment: So here is what Oracle MV pre-requisites say - `When you create a materialized view, Oracle Database creates one internal table and at least one index, and may create one view, all in the schema of the materialized view. Oracle Database uses these objects to maintain the materialized view data. You must have the privileges necessary to create these objects.` that could probably explain the CTAS.

Answer (score 1):

I will consolidate my comments in this answer. There could be one of these multiple reasons why a CTAS would fire-

1. There is a DDL Trigger at the schema level which does a CTAS, although unlikely unless custom DDL triggers are in place.
2. There is another possibility that could fire a CTAS which is the `ON PREBUILT TABLE` clause while creating the MV, but I don't see that being used.
3. Oracle MV [pre-requisites](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6002.htm#i2162987) say -

> When you create a materialized view, Oracle Database **creates one**
>   *internal table* and at least one index, and may create one view, all in
>   the schema of the materialized view. Oracle Database uses these
>   objects to maintain the materialized view data. You must have the
>   privileges necessary to create these objects.

that could probably explain the CTAS.

So far, point 3. looks like the best explanation for the CTAS you are seeing.

Comment: since `ON PREBUILT TABLE` will **not** create a table (but instead reuse an existing one), I doubt it would be a valid reason to use CTAS =). This also doesn't explain why the statement is seen only when the procedure is called from the scheduler.

Comment: I am not sure if it show up "only" from the scheduler. If it shows up from the scheduler, then it would show up if run from anywhere else.